# Dark mode in Chrome without turning on it on Windows?

Tags: google-chrome

According to [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9275525?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0), I can turn on dark mode in `Chrome`, only when it has been turned on `Windows`. But, I don't need dark mode on `Windows`.
I try to use respective theme, but in this case I don't have custom background on the new page.
So, what to do?